# NodeMCU SPI Module too fast

Tags: spi, esp8266, nodemcu, shift-register

I really want to make use of the SPI module on my NodeMCU. SPI keeps my code clean and frees up some of my GPIO pins. I feel it is sending data too fast for my 74HC595 to keep up with. It was working for a bit, then stopped.

It seemed like there was a lot of noise on the line so I hooked up the logic analyzer and saw that when I was sending data, bits were flying across the line at almost 6 ns (which is awesome). I am driving a 595 and ultimately a stepper, that need data at a way slower rate. I have tried using the clock parameter in the setup call, I feel it never slows the SPI clock.

Is there any way to set the clock speed to something that would be more 595+stepper friendly?

Comment: What version of NodeMcu are you running? If you haven't tried a dev branch build you may want to give that a shot. http://nodemcu-build.com

Comment: I have been using the dev branches and making my own firmware from: http://nodemcu-build.com

Comment: Just thought I'd check, since I didn't see that anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at [the docs](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/spi/) in the most recent dev branch of NodeMCU (get it from the [NodeMCU Build website](http://nodemcu-build.com/)) you can setup SPI with a divider to lower the data rate of the SPI transmissions (higher div, lower bit rate):

`spi.setup(id, mode, cpol, cpha, databits, clock_div[, duplex_mode])`

Parameters include:

**clock_div** -  SPI clock divider, f(SPI) = f(CPU) / clock_div

Comment: Thank you for the info. Try as I might, no matter what I put in the clock_div, the thing would still run crazy fast.